Is a single hour enough for Google AutoML training 1000 images with single objects in it?
I am a newbie AI practitioner. Please don't be too harsh.
I'm currently looking at the pricing for AutoML for Google Vision Vertex AI. The pricing is in per hour. Let's say I have 1000 image files. Each image file contains only 1 object. I want to use these images for training a model in AutoML.
Is a single hour enough for these 1000 images for the training?

You're missing a lot of detail here. For instance, how many object categories do you have? What exactly is the task you're trying to do anyway? Also, what's stopping you from just trying and see how far you come?
